# Desirability of blood groups from recipient’s perspective

Tags: blood-donation, mathematics

To keep things simple, I limit myself to considering the ABO-Rh system. The associated antigens and antibodies induce a relation we can call the *can-donate-to* relation on the groups, so for example, A– can donate to AB– (because the only antigen that can cause problems for Mr. AB– is Rh(D), and the only antigen that Ms. A– provides is A).

I note that mathematicians would see *can-donate-to* as a partial order on the set of the 8 blood groups and would recognize the system more specifically as having the structure of the Boolean lattice *B*<sub>3</sub>.

I know that I myself for example, being A+, **can** receive transfusions of any of O–, A–, O+, and A+. And from the point of view of a dispensing blood bank, I imagine they’d wish to provide me a type as near mine as possible, simply to maximize the utility of their remaining inventory. On that reasoning, they’d prefer not to “waste” blood carrying few antigens on an insensitive lout like me who produces only one flavor of antibodies, the B.

But from the perspective of me, the recipient, is there any sense in which my physiology would **prefer** any of the four acceptable types over any of the others? As an example, is there any sense in which I’d be better off receiving, say, a unit of A+ rather than a unit of A–, O+, or O–?

Comment: "...from the perspective of me, the donor, is there any sense in which..." From that perspective, this question makes no sense whatsoever. If you're the donor, there's no consideration given to your receiving blood, period.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, I hope it’s clear that that was a typo. In any event, I’ve fixed it.

Comment: No, it wasn't clear that it was a typo, but it helps to read it as it was likely meant. As you've now corrected it, haven't you answered your question in the first and third paragraphs? Blood banks always **type & cross** unless someone is bleeding out. That's means (for you) A+ plus checking for other antigens.  Donors need not worry.

Comment: No, my question remains. I know that, for instance, I myself **can** take any of four blood types. But is there anything that would lead me to care **which** of those four I did receive? Any sense in which any of those four would be "better for me" than any of the others?

Comment: Seriously? Why do you think **TYPE & cross** is bolded?

Comment: Ok, @anongoodnurse, so I’m stupid. I do not know why you bolded *type & cross*. Nor has reading, for instance, [this](https://www.healthline.com/health/blood-typing-and-crossmatching) clarified it for me. As I wrote in the OP, I’m asking only about ABO and Rh (yes, I know there’s a lot more, but I’m trying to keep my question simple.) And not about me (I was merely an example). If a recipient is, say, B+, can it matter to that recipient’s health which of O–, O+, B–, and B+ blood they receive. If so, then how/why would it matter to the recipient?